# Difficulty creating creating simple test for android "hello world" programme

Tags: java, android

Hey guys i need some help testing a Hello world programme in android studio . Heres what i have tried , i basically just made a empty project and by default you get the "Hello world" programme .

now i need to test this "hello world" application I.E. once i run the test , the test should check if "Hello world" is displayed in the emulator.

now if you check the google testing page [here](https://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-basic-testing.html)

you will see that there is already a snippet there to do exactly the same , see the snippet below :

```
public void testMyFirstTestTextView_labelText() {
    final String expected =
            mFirstTestActivity.getString(R.string.my_first_test);
    final String actual = mFirstTestText.getText().toString();
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

this snippet needs to be edited for it to work obviously , so i edit it ,see below :

```
public void testMyFirstTestTextView_labelText() {
        final String expected =
                MainActivity.getString(R.string.hello_world); // added //MainActivity as thats the name of my activity and hello_would as thats the //variable i have in strings.xal
        final String actual = mFirstTestText.getText().toString();
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

now there is still a error i get the `getString` after `MainActivity` shows a red underline in android studio and if i hover over it shows the following error :

> Non-static method "getString(int)" cannot be referanced from static
>   context.

and then if i hover over `mFirstTestText` i get the following error :

> connot resolve symbol `mFirstTestText` .

now i have no idea what to replace these 2 method/variables with , can somebody help me understand/solve this issue ?

The entire Main class code ::

```
package com.example.gautam.orbita;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess for the `mFirstTestText` i should have the following `android.widget.TextView` but then i get a error on getText() , saying `Non-static method "getText()" cannot be referanced from static context.`  , the entire line of code looks like so `final String actual = android.widget.TextView.getText().toString();` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code shown `mFirstTestText` is not initialized.

## EDIT

I will shown an example here on what you class should look like, to change the text of a TextView, in simpler terms:

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
TextView aTextView; 
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_example);
    aTextView = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.aTextView);
    aTextView.setText("An example text");
  }
```

#### activity_main_example.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/aTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ! i have posted the entire main class code , i hope i am making sense :)

Comment: As far as I can read, your class is correct, but empty, as in there are no commands to do what you desire. Post 2 additional files, the AndroidManifest.xml and the MainActivity.xml .... since you appear to be new on the Android system, please, reffer to the Activiy lifecyle. Finally, what I can offer is: on the `onCreate` function, start a variable with a textfield, then use that variable to change the contents of the textfield... The "snippet" you found, is not the best starting point in my opinion.